# How to store 'query-able' encrypted data in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

I need a way to store encrypted data, in a way that I can still run queries. Is that even possible?

At least I need an encryption algorythm that always returns the same string for the same input, so I can find all the users named 'John' by encrypting that string and looking for the encrypted result in the DB. In PHP, mcrypt always returns different strings (I know this is on purpose, to improve security).

Any ideas?

Comment: In order to store encrypted data in mysql, it would need to decrypt it (assuming this was done with mysql not php) to perform the keyword search. This would be insanely slow as even indexes couldn't help you then.

Comment: I've got an idea of asking you why do you need to store encrypted data?

Comment: Because it's data that should only be readable for people that has been authorized in the web application (not in the DB). Many people work with this DB and have read access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on how you're storing that 'John' name. If it's the ONLY thing in a particular field, you can do something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable
WHERE cryptedfirstname = AES_ENCRYPT('John', $key)
```

If 'John' is part of a larger string ('John Doe' or 'King John, Ruler of the Universe'), then you'll have to decrypt the full field and match against that

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometime
WHERE INSTR(AES_DECRYPT(cryptedFULLame, $key), 'John') > 0
```

Note that I'm embedding the decryption key in the query. Bad idea for a production system, but this is just an example.

You won't be able to do something like:

```
...
WHERE INSTR(cryptedFULLname, AES_ENCRYPT('John', $key))
```

due to how AES and most other userful/decent crypto systems work.

Comment: Thanks, very useful. Some idiot -1'ed you, clearly he didn't understand the problem. +1

Comment: No biggies. Downvotes fly around thick and fast here. And frankly, -1 doesn't make that much of a difference at this point...

Comment: The down-vote wasn't from me, but it may have been from someone who understands that good security requires a cipher mode with an unpredictable IV. All of the examples here lack that.

Comment: @erickson: which means kudos to the downvoter for being aware of that, but 50 smacks with a wet fish for failing reading comprehension where I said "this is just an example"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you understand this, but it should be emphasized that an encryption algorithm that always produces the same cipher text for a given plain text is broken. It leads to all kinds of attacks.

For example, an attacker with access to your database and the application can choose the value "John" for a field, and cause the application to store it in the database. Then he can look at the cipher text for his record, and identify any other records that contain that cipher text. He doesn't need to obtain the key for this.

An exception would be if you are encrypting large, "unpredictable" unique numbers, for example, session identifiers or UUIDs. In this case, since the plain texts don't recur, and valid plaintexts can't be predicted by an attacker, ciphertext indistinguishability is not required.

Any symmetric cipher used in ECB mode will produce consistent ciphertext from a plaintext, as will using modes that take an initialization vector if you always use the same IV. It's just generally not a good idea to do this.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Well, someone else in the company will have to deal with this =p, I didn't design the system. +1